# Float Variable is not saving into playerprefs How Do I Fix This Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I'm trying to save the float variable ***cors.Destroyers*** each time my player collides with a coin I make that ***equal = 1*** and then I make sure when I click the ***KEY S*** it should be saved onto my player prefab ***but when I relaunch the game for some reason it goes back to 0*** I been trying to fix this for a while now and I'm still not sure why it isn't saving at all but when I try to to make my variable ***static it works but I don't want it to be  a static variable I want it to work without static variable somehow*** any help is greatfully appreciated

```c
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
public class savegameprogress2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public COINS cors;

    private void Start()
    {
        LoadGame();
        //Debug.Log(COINS.gamecoin);
        Debug.Log(cors.Destroyers);
    }
    void Update()
    {


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
        SaveGame();

        }
    }
    public void SaveGame()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmoney", COINS.gamecoin );
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("destroy", cors.Destroyers);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log("Game data saved!");
    }
    void LoadGame()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("SavedInteger"))
        {
            //save for scene 2
            COINS.gamecoin = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmoney");
            cors.Destroyers = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("destroy");
        }
        else
            Debug.LogError("There is no save data!");
    }
```

Comment: Where do you ever write the key `SavedInteger`? If you never write it, the condition `if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("SavedInteger"))` will never pass and you'll never have actual data. Can you also show more code? What is the structure of the `COINS` class / object?

Comment: Based on your code, you never set SavedInteger, so it skips the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Make these adjustments to the code:**

- In start method, check if the key exists in the player preferences by
  using HasKey method. If it doesn't exist, assign a 0 value.
- Before quitting the game, make sure that the preferences are saved onto the disk.

**Code:**

```
void Start(){
    if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("mainmoney")){
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmoney", 0);
    }
    if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("destroy")){
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("destroy", 0);
    }
}

void OnApplicationQuit(){
    PlayerPrefs.Save;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned before I don't see you ever setting anything in the `PlayerPrefs` using the key `SavedInteger` at all!

So either you haven't shared an important detail with us and this is actually set somewhere else ... or it will simply never exist.

---

You probably would want to do this e.g.

```
public void SaveGame()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmoney", COINS.gamecoin );
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("destroy", cors.Destroyers);
    // The actual type and value doesn't matter since you only check for the existence of the key
    PlayerPRefs.SetInt("SavedInteger", 1);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    Debug.Log("Game data saved!");
}
```

alternatviely you already **have** at least two other keys you could/should check for instead of introducing a new one. You could rather simply check for

```
if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("mainmoney"))
```

---

General Note: You should rather introduce some `const` fields for the keys instead of having hardcoded `string` values everywhere. It prevents typos and makes it easier to rename the key later on in only one central point

```
private const string MAINMONEY = "mainmoney";
private const string DESTROY = "destroy";
```

and then rather sue

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(MAINMONEY, COINS.gamecoin );
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(DESTROY, cors.Destroyers);
```

and

```
if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey(MAINMONEY))
{
    COINS.gamecoin = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(MAINMONEY);
    cors.Destroyers = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(DESTROY);
    ...
```